# Adding application reference on right click from on any text on MacOSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I saw this TextWrangler has option to create new text document by right clicking on any selected on MacOSX. I was planning to make an application and I have intension to add very similar feature. So the question is,

- How to add this feature?
- Do I need Apple's permission?

---

Visual Description :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is known as a "Service", information on how they work and how to implement them can be found in the [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/).